# Magento 2 : How to creating a dynamic row system config with an image option?

Tags: magento2

I have a module that is creating dynamically generated admin fields with Image upload it's not saving and showing in the admin panel.

Is their any way it can be implemented ?
[image]

I have added the image field in dynamic rows like below

```
$this->addColumn(
    'image',
    [
    'label' => __('Image'),
    'renderer' => $this->getImageRenderer()
]);
private function getImageRenderer()
{
    if (!$this->imageRenderer) {
        $this->imageRenderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            \Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Blocks\Edit\Tab\ImageRenderer::class,
            '',
            ['data' => ['is_render_to_js_template' => true]]
        );
    }
    return $this->imageRenderer;
}
```

ImageRenderer class

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Blocks\Edit\Tab;

class ImageRenderer extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $html = '<input type="file" name="' . $this->getInputName() . '" id="' . $this->getInputId() . '" ';
        $html .= '<image name="' . $this->getInputName() . '" id="' . $this->getInputId() . '" />';
        return $html;
    }
}
```

Comment: any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

Check this

https://magento-qa.com/how-to-create-a-dynamic-generated-admin-fields-with-image-upload

I hope it will help you